# Visual Input into Numerical Input

Tags: input

I am working on writing a program that plays Microsoft Solitaire by itself. I am looking for a way to allow the program to read visual input from the screen and convert that into a numerical form (most likely integers). Specifically I would like to read the visuals of the cards and convert that into an int from 1-52 representing that card value.

The specific programing language does not matter I am simply interested in how this could be achieved in any capacity. Although, I am more familiar with Java and python so if this is possible in those languages that might be easier for me.

I apologize if there is a well-documented or widely-known way to handle this but I am a relatively novice programmer with little to no experience outside of text based inputs.

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Comment: You're going to have to pick a language and do some homework and show where you specifically get stuck. Otherwise, this will become a matter of opinion and get closed for being off-topic. FYI, just about any compute language has a canonical way to convert text input to numeric.

Comment: I know of ways to convert text into numerical values no problem, what I don't know how to do is convert visual input from the screen into text.

Comment: That's a whole other area which depends heavily upon what kind of system you're talking about. Is this a we app? A Widows app? And each language has one or more frameworks for doing things visually.

Comment: (1) get a handle to the Solitaire window, (2) grab that portion of the screen, (3) loop over 'known offsets' (the cards appear in predictable positions) and test the pixels for the values you need to discriminate "jack of hearts" from "ace of spades".

Comment: This will be a windows app. If I need to decide on a particular language to focus on I would prefer Java. I have no problem doing the research for the nitty gritty but I need help being pointed in the right direction. What am I looking for to get me started?

Comment: Arguably one of the more popular platforms for developing a Windows application (resulting in an `exe` file and associated components, if needed) would be Microsoft Visual Studio. But if you don't mind programming in Pascal, there's Lazarus, which uses Free Pascal and it, itself, is free and provides all sorts of visual components for Windows. You might want to play around with something like that a bit and see where it leads you before you go directly to trying to write a Solitaire game. You could try Googling for others, as I don't claim to be up on all the latest Windows game tools.

Comment: What programming experience do you have?

Comment: I really appreciate all of the help, this is exactly the kind of information I was looking for to get me started. I am currently working on a CS degree and my programing experience had been mostly limited to class projects in various object oriented languages. Outside of that I have little experience. I was looking to work on this project in my free time to learn what I could in something that sounded interesting to me

Comment: If you're considering web applications, have a look at Ruby (language) and Rails (framework).